# Capturing images from Webcam using picturebox

Tags: c#-2.0

I have a windowsform with two pictureboxes to capture images from webcam. The first picturebox display the webcam image and the second picturebox display the captured image.
Then how to write code to get images from the webcam and preview the captured image in the second picturebox. pls help me

advance thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I have already answered this

[In windows application how can i save a live image from webcam in picturebox using C#.Net 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989595/in-windows-application-how-can-i-save-a-live-image-from-webcam-in-picturebox-usi/17989851#17989851)