# In windows application how can i save a live image from webcam in picturebox using C#.Net 2.0

Tags: c#, webcam

i am doing a windows application and there is a requirement to capture the person's photo lively before saving it in the separate folder

able to get live video in picturebox but doesn't know how to save it in any specfied format in  button click event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to save the image and got the expected result.

add the .DLL file if you need this feature in your project

Just check the below URL to download the code

http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/showcode.asp?lngWId=10&txtCodeId=1339

Answer (score 4):

Here is the Code .. First  Download the DLLRefrence and add as Reference in Visual Studio..

Link for DLL   http://www.mediafire.com/?dxrnc433pfrp7mu

and copy paste this code in your program

```
namespace WinFormCharpWebCam
   {
      partial class mainWinForm
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.imgVideo = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
        this.imgCapture = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
        this.bntStart = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.bntStop = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.bntContinue = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.bntCapture = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.bntSave = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.bntVideoFormat = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.bntVideoSource = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.imgVideo)).BeginInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.imgCapture)).BeginInit();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // imgVideo
        // 
        this.imgVideo.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Stretch;
        this.imgVideo.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(55, 41);
        this.imgVideo.Name = "imgVideo";
        this.imgVideo.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(163, 160);
        this.imgVideo.TabIndex = 0;
        this.imgVideo.TabStop = false;
        // 
        // imgCapture
        // 
        this.imgCapture.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Stretch;
        this.imgCapture.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(242, 41);
        this.imgCapture.Name = "imgCapture";
        this.imgCapture.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(163, 160);
        this.imgCapture.TabIndex = 1;
        this.imgCapture.TabStop = false;
        // 
        // bntStart
        // 
        this.bntStart.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(55, 216);
        this.bntStart.Name = "bntStart";
        this.bntStart.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(41, 23);
        this.bntStart.TabIndex = 2;
        this.bntStart.Text = "Start";
        this.bntStart.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.bntStart.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.bntStart_Click);
        // 
        // bntStop
        // 
        this.bntStop.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(102, 216);
        this.bntStop.Name = "bntStop";
        this.bntStop.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(49, 23);
        this.bntStop.TabIndex = 3;
        this.bntStop.Text = "Stop";
        this.bntStop.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.bntStop.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.bntStop_Click);
        // 
        // bntContinue
        // 
        this.bntContinue.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(157, 216);
        this.bntContinue.Name = "bntContinue";
        this.bntContinue.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(61, 23);
        this.bntContinue.TabIndex = 4;
        this.bntContinue.Text = "Continue";
        this.bntContinue.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.bntContinue.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.bntContinue_Click);
        // 
        // bntCapture
        // 
        this.bntCapture.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(242, 216);
        this.bntCapture.Name = "bntCapture";
        this.bntCapture.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(85, 23);
        this.bntCapture.TabIndex = 5;
        this.bntCapture.Text = "Capture Image";
        this.bntCapture.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.bntCapture.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.bntCapture_Click);
        // 
        // bntSave
        // 
        this.bntSave.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(326, 216);
        this.bntSave.Name = "bntSave";
        this.bntSave.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(79, 23);
        this.bntSave.TabIndex = 6;
        this.bntSave.Text = "Save Image";
        this.bntSave.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.bntSave.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.bntSave_Click);
        // 
        // bntVideoFormat
        // 
        this.bntVideoFormat.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(425, 100);
        this.bntVideoFormat.Name = "bntVideoFormat";
        this.bntVideoFormat.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(147, 23);
        this.bntVideoFormat.TabIndex = 7;
        this.bntVideoFormat.Text = "Video Format";
        this.bntVideoFormat.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.bntVideoFormat.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.bntVideoFormat_Click);
        // 
        // bntVideoSource
        // 
        this.bntVideoSource.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(425, 129);
        this.bntVideoSource.Name = "bntVideoSource";
        this.bntVideoSource.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(147, 23);
        this.bntVideoSource.TabIndex = 8;
        this.bntVideoSource.Text = "Video Source";
        this.bntVideoSource.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.bntVideoSource.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.bntVideoSource_Click);
        // 
        // mainWinForm
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(584, 362);
        this.Controls.Add(this.bntVideoSource);
        this.Controls.Add(this.bntVideoFormat);
        this.Controls.Add(this.bntSave);
        this.Controls.Add(this.bntCapture);
        this.Controls.Add(this.bntContinue);
        this.Controls.Add(this.bntStop);
        this.Controls.Add(this.bntStart);
        this.Controls.Add(this.imgCapture);
        this.Controls.Add(this.imgVideo);
        this.Name = "mainWinForm";
        this.Text = "WinForm C# WebCam";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.mainWinForm_Load);
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.imgVideo)).EndInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.imgCapture)).EndInit();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox imgVideo;
    private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox imgCapture;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button bntStart;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button bntStop;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button bntContinue;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button bntCapture;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button bntSave;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button bntVideoFormat;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button bntVideoSource;
}
 }




using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace WinFormCharpWebCam
{
public partial class mainWinForm : Form
{
    public mainWinForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    WebCam webcam;
    private void mainWinForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webcam = new WebCam();
        webcam.InitializeWebCam(ref imgVideo);
    }

    private void bntStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webcam.Start();
    }

    private void bntStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webcam.Stop();
    }

    private void bntContinue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webcam.Continue();
    }

    private void bntCapture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        imgCapture.Image = imgVideo.Image;
    }

    private void bntSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Helper.SaveImageCapture(imgCapture.Image);
    }

    private void bntVideoFormat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webcam.ResolutionSetting();
    }

    private void bntVideoSource_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webcam.AdvanceSetting();
    }


}
 }

 using System;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using WebCam_Capture;
 using System.Collections.Generic;



namespace WinFormCharpWebCam
 {

class WebCam
{
    private WebCamCapture webcam;
    private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox _FrameImage;
    private int FrameNumber = 30;
    public void InitializeWebCam(ref System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox ImageControl)
    {
        webcam = new WebCamCapture();
        webcam.FrameNumber = ((ulong)(0ul));
        webcam.TimeToCapture_milliseconds = FrameNumber;
        webcam.ImageCaptured += new WebCamCapture.WebCamEventHandler(webcam_ImageCaptured);
        _FrameImage = ImageControl;
    }

    void webcam_ImageCaptured(object source, WebcamEventArgs e)
    {
        _FrameImage.Image = e.WebCamImage;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        webcam.TimeToCapture_milliseconds = FrameNumber;
        webcam.Start(0);
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        webcam.Stop();
    }

    public void Continue()
    {
        // change the capture time frame
        webcam.TimeToCapture_milliseconds = FrameNumber;

        // resume the video capture from the stop
        webcam.Start(this.webcam.FrameNumber);
    }

    public void ResolutionSetting()
    {
        webcam.Config();
    }

    public void AdvanceSetting()
    {
        webcam.Config2();
    }

}
}


using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace WinFormCharpWebCam
{

class Helper
{

    public static void SaveImageCapture(System.Drawing.Image image)
    {

        SaveFileDialog s = new SaveFileDialog();
        s.FileName = "Image";// Default file name
        s.DefaultExt = ".Jpg";// Default file extension
        s.Filter = "Image (.jpg)|*.jpg"; // Filter files by extension

        // Show save file dialog box
        // Process save file dialog box results
        if (s.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // Save Image
            string filename = s.FileName;
            FileStream fstream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);
            image.Save(fstream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            fstream.Close();

        }

    }
}
 }
```

if its working  ... Don't say thanks ... Accept this answer by Tick it... :)

Comment: you can accept the answer by voting it or Tick to say answer is correct !!

Comment: how to get Using System.Linq namespace in VS2005.. i dont think it is there in VS2005..may be it is predefined in higher version of VS.

Comment: Try to upgrade VS to 2010 atleast

Comment: Instead of saying thanks .. Accept the answer ... plz... by ticking it

Comment: i have found solution in VS2005 itself so thanks for your time

Comment: I said no need to say thanks...just Tick the Answer by accepting ... Vote for my answer...

Comment: hi aarvind i haven't used your code or tried in VS2010 as you said  but just found the solution in VS2005 itself.. so how i can accept your code as answer?

Comment: @Alok I added .dll file from the project got from below URL & did some modification in the project according to my requirement. It works fine now http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/showcode.asp?lngWId=10&txtCodeId=1339